# What is the purpose of the EnumerableRowCollection<TRow> class?

Tags: .net, linq, datatable

As it states in the documentation [`DataTable.AsEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns an IEnumerable<T> object, where the generic parameter T is DataRow. This object can be used in a LINQ expression or method query.

But the return type of `AsEnumerable()` is not simply an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` it is also an `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>`

Why have this type? What benefit does it provide over say `DataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()` which only provides an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`?

Comment: I guess the difference is not visible/important outside of the framework since everything is `private` or `internal`. [Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/EnumerableRowCollection.cs,58e9b1a0e95c8bad,references) you can see the implementation details.

Comment: I'm not a dataset expert because I typically try to avoid it, but a quick glance at the source seems to indicate that it does something special with the dataset's sorting and filtering, while `IEnumerable<DataRow>` would not.

Comment: You are using [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method from `System.Data` namespace, not from `System.Linq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page for [`EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979(v=vs.110).aspx) there 
are several extension methods which specifically take and return an `EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>` from this I assume that there are `DataTable` specific implementations for these methods that can not be used when simply using an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

I also found this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erickt/archive/2007/11/06/what-is-this-enumerablerowco) which states

> In order for LinqDataView to work without using IQueryable (which we didn’t want to do for performance reasons), we have to hold on to the implementation class. As long as are working with a EnumerableRowCollection instance instead of a “something” which implements IEnumerable we can capture each LINQ operator into a state bag which allows us to recreate the effects of the LINQ query in a DataView.

I had thought that LINQ-To-Objects covered any use of LINQ with IEnumerables and anything else meant IQueryables were used but I guess that is not the case. `IQueryable<T>` also implements `IEnumerable<T>` but it has *many* more IQueryable specific extension methods available than `DataRowCollection<TRow>`